# Apache Mod-rewrite across domains?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, heroku

OK, I have a site, at www.domain.com.  I added a web app on heroku and it has it Heroku URL and a custom domain.  However, what I'd like to do is have it accessible via those two URL but on the www.domain.com site, I'd like to access that new server via www.domain.com/customapp. I figured I could do it through URL rewrite.  But all the examples I see are doing the the other way, so is my idea possible?  Is mod-rewrite the way to go?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try setting up a reverse proxy for www.domain.com? Assuming you are using Apache 2.2, it's pretty easy to do if you have access to the httpd.conf or httpd-vhosts.conf file.

In your case I would add the following to your httpd.conf or httpd-vhosts.conf file.

```
ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass /customapp/ <URL-to-Heroku-App>
ProxyPassReverse /customapp/ <URL-to-Heroku-App>
```

For more information, see the docs.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse

Comment: Hmmm, i entered that into my httpd.conf and nothing happened, I just get my 404 page..  does it need to be before anything in the file?  I just put it at the end.

Comment: Tried something list this page as well, no dice: http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies

Comment: Make sure your Apache was compiled with mod_proxy. Place the Proxy code above after your domain's `<Directory></Directory>` block in your httpd.conf file. Don't forget to bounce apache after the changes are in place.